# C# how to change the microsoft installer(msi) content created property value in the details tab of its properties?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

i have created a setup and deployment project in VS 2008 for my windows form application, but i am unable to find how to change the content created property value in the details tab of the microsoft installer (msi) properties.

Comment: Where have you looked, what have you tried?

Comment: @JoshuaDrake go to images.google.com type (msi property details tab) the first image result u get, see the content created date in the details tab. In my msi file the content created date is showing as 21-Jun-99 12.30 PM. How can i can change it ?

Comment: Are you by chance including SQL Scripts/Configuration in your installer?

Comment: No. I just made my desktop icon non-advertised using orca. Did you see the image I mentioned you ?

Comment: Ahh yes, the dread Advertised Shortcut!  I did see the image and the property in question, I believe, is a file attribute coming from the filesystem and not isolated to MSI files.  Did the MSI display the incorrect date before being edited?

Comment: Yes, it was incorrect from beginning. I can set the values to Authors, Title property from within VS2008. But i can't find content created option in the setup project properties in VS 2008.

Comment: As mentioned I do not believe that property is changeable from within VS2008 as it is part of the underlying operating system.  The only other thought that I had was to check the creation dates of all files included in your project, possibly including referenced system dlls.  My guess is that the system is picking that date based on your actual content, since it is obviously not the date the MSI was created.  Finally, I assume you are building all this in Release mode, correct?

Comment: Yes, I am building all the stuff in Release mode. I checked the date of each and every item of my project and they all are correct except only this property value. Did you try on your side ?

Comment: My OS, XP x64, does not display that property at all for the MSI I created, that is why I mentioned that it is a property of the file system and not the MSI itself, hence why it does not show up as a property in Visual Studio.

Comment: I have the same question for VS2010 (NET 4) on Win7 Pro 64-bit, though my date shows '1999-Jun-21 02:00'.  Could it be that the value is somehow indicating Visual Studio or Windows Installer version (though i fail to see a purpose in that)?  It cannot have anything to do with fiesystem dates, as all 3 (Created, Modified and Accessed) are set to '2012-Sep-28 11:09:53'.  

In my .msi Properties dialog there is also 'Revision number' GUID, which i do not see exposed in VS2010 project.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905.aspx does not mention either of these.